# Azure TFS/SQL firewall connection outside server

Tags: sql-server, azure, tfs, virtual-machine, azure-web-app-service

Hey all I am in need of some help setting up TFS on my Azure windows server 2016 VM.

I think i have all my firewall rules set up but i'm not that sure if i do or not. I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/architecture/required-ports?view=tfs-2017) site as an example.

[image]

However, I am not able to reach it outside of my server using my domain name like so:

http://mydomain.me:8080/tfs

[image]

I have also tested out my connecting outside of my server for my SQL 2017 and it seems i cannot connect to that either.

[image]

What am i missing in order for me to connect to both the SQL and TFS from outside the server?

Comment: If you're already going to use cloud services, why not migrate to Visual Studio Team Services? Then you don't have to mess around with managing infrastructure in Azure.

Comment: You may check this blog to see whether it helps you: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mihansen/2017/11/15/private-tfs-deployment-in-azure/

Answer (score 0):

Firmware rules are not enough to access TFS set up in Azure. The basic topology looks something like the illustration below:

[image]

In a virtual network, it establishes a new domain with two domain controllers and deploys a TFS server, a database, and a TFS agent. To access the virtual network, the pattern includes a jump box; another strategy would be to add a VPN gateway, but for simplicity we are going with the jump box.

You can check the blog below for more information:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mihansen/2017/11/15/private-tfs-deployment-in-azure/

Or you could consider migrating to VSTS as @Daniel's mentioned.